# git trying to commit thousands of files

Tags: xcode, git

i am trying to commit changes to a project in Xcode 4.6.3
i have used the Source Control -> Commit mechanism several times and it worked beautifully
i recently added DCRoundSwitch objects to my project (https://github.com/domesticcatsoftware/DCRoundSwitch)
when i now try to commit changes, Xcode hangs for a loooong time then tells me it wants to commit 100,875 files (in the past my commits ran between a few and a few dozen files), and every so often it crashes out.  i tried doing the commit to no avail.

it appears git is trying to commit all files in all linked libraries, in addition to all my source files.  it was not attempting this prior to my adding the DCRoundSwitch files

i went online and read about .gitignore files and created one in my project directory (not the git subdirectory of the project directly)...it had no effect on the behavior

fwiw, the content of that .gitignore file is below.

any help much appreciated

```
#Xcode
.DS_Store
*/build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap

#CocoaPods
Pods
```

Comment: Does "git status" show the large # of files? You cold try to "git stash save" the files, then create the .gitignore file and commit it, then "git stash pop" and do a "git status" to see if there still is a huge list of files to commit (hopefully there will not be).

Comment: how do i get the git status?  is this something i do from Terminal?  also, should .gitignore be in the project directory or the .git subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, from the command line you can do "git status" and see what files in your repo are modified, but not committed. Good idea to get used to the command line as there are many things you can do. The .gitignore will go at the top of the repository tree (not in the .git directory) and you can put files and directories in ther and use wildcards. IIRC, it won't be "applied" to the repo, until you commit it, hence the suggestion to stash - or you can just "git add" the .gitignore file and commit that, and then use "git status" to see what files it "sees".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

From the command line do a "git reset"  This will reset git without touching the file system.  You'll need to do a git add *file name* to re-add the files you were trying to add before.

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue - should have been a couple of changes, but each file was duplicated a hundred times. Resetting did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you've added the entire project from github to your project, you are probably trying to add all the files, included those from the git repository of the project.

It would be better if you added the project as a git submodule. I mean you have a git repository, and you are importing another git repository to it. That way, you aren't inflating your repository.